# Does EclipseLink support ORDER BY FIELD(field, :values)

Tags: jakarta-ee, jpa, eclipselink, jpql

MySQL supports queries such as:

```
SELECT id FROM users WHERE id IN(3,4,8,1) ORDER BY FIELD(id, 3,4,8,1);
```

Does EclipseLink support this query (without reverting to a native query)?

When I try the following:

```
Select id from User user where user.id in :ids ORDER BY FIELD(user.id, :ids)
```

I receive the error:

```
Syntax error parsing the query ... line 1, column 98: unexpected token [(].
```

Comment: clearly that is not valid JPQL, so no JPA implementation would "support" it without (non-portable) vendor extensions. JPQL does allow "FUNCTION" where you could put your FIELD thing in (and that is portable JPQL)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ORDER BY FIELD(field, :values)` is not supported by JPA (JQL) or EclipseLink.

JPA does provide a mechanism to execute native queries. You could create a native query to invoke a query similar to that in your description, however, it of course, would not be portable.